# Matrices and vectors calculating angle.

Tags: vectors

I've got an exam in January, and i've been looking over past papers. There seems to be a recurrence for the following question :

> Calculate the angle between the vectors $\mathbf u=\begin{pmatrix}-8 \\
> 15\end{pmatrix}$ and $\mathbf v=\begin{pmatrix}-23 \\
> 7\end{pmatrix}$.
>
> You can use the following table to work out the angle from its cosine: 
>   $$
> \begin{array}{|c|c|}
> \hline\\ \cos\phi  & 1 & \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}2 & \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}2 & \dfrac12 & 0 & -\dfrac12 & -\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}2 & -\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}2 & -1     \\ \\
> \hline
> \\\\
> \phi & 0° & 30° & 45° & 60° & 90° & 120° & 135° & 150° & 180°  \\ \\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> $$

I know how to multiply matrices, that's about all i know how to do though =/

Could someone show me a basic process in how this should be done, in a way that will actually help me understand for the exam; bare in mind im bad at maths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\cos(\theta) = \frac{v_1w_1+v_2w_2+v_3w_3}{|v||w|} \qquad v=\left(v_1,v_2,v_3\right), w=\left(w_1,w_2,w_3\right)$$

The numerator is the arithmetical way for the dot product, and the denominator is based on the geometrical way of getting the dot product:

$$|v|=\sqrt{ v_1^2+v_2^2+v_3^2}$$

So, in the numerator, you take the correspond values in $v$ times those in $w$ and in the denomentato

EX:

$$\cos(\theta) = \frac{-8\times -23+15\times 7}{\sqrt{(-8)^2+15^2}\sqrt{(-23)^2+7^2}}$$

**EDIT:**
For the new pairs of vectors in the comments:
$$\cos(\theta) = \frac{(-6)\times 7+12\times (-5)}{\sqrt{(-6)^2+12^2}\times \sqrt{7^2+(-5)^2}}$$

Comment: I was attempting the other guys comment and i thought he implied for me to times it out, heres the beginning.. but surely this is wrong lol ? http://vvcap.net/db/7stBtj6nfcSp2lVWldL7.htp

Comment: Here is the answer: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=angle+between+%288%2C15%29+and%28-23%2C7%29

Comment: That's just me not really having an understand of the differences i thought he wanted me to times them out -.- the example you gave looks ok, if i memorised that would that be enough to get the answer? also whats the reason for 1 next to the -8 ?

Comment: it's a typo I think

Comment: It will be enough for the answer, but as I you said, you will have to memorize the entire equation. What @MJD did was to explain how to derive this equation.

Comment: Also do you always square root it and put each number in dominator to power of 2 ? why?

Comment: Otherwise, you need to memorize two basic facts that would lead to what I wrote in the answer, that is diff. ways of obtaining the dot product for two vectors.

Comment: yes! this is the way of calculating the magnitude. Think about Pythagoras' theorem!

Comment: Make sure you stay online ive rewritten another question and done it using your way, let me just do it in paint haha :D

Comment: ok! Btw, you can think of the denominator as the distance formula in a two-dimensional coordinate system.

Comment: Please up-vote if you liked my answer! :)

Comment: btw when calculating the numerator on the calculator i got 289 yet the link u sent me said its 79

Comment: maybe I plugged in wrong values in the eq.. I will check

Comment: 289 is right. I forgot that 8 was negative in the link: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=angle+between+%28-8%2C15%29+and%28-23%2C7%29

Comment: figured it out :O ?

Comment: this is as far as i can go : http://vvcap.net/db/skkSfEssQDqUlGQlOBWr.htp

Comment: wait, the square root  should be taken from both (-6)^2 and 12^2 together

Comment: Do you mean because i missed a bracket ? that was a typo or you made an error ?

Comment: take a look at my edit

Comment: hmmm not much of a difference is there ?

Comment: the square root sign

Comment: What's the difference -.- ?

Comment: please take a look at  my edits

Comment: I see what you're doing, but trying to look at edits just fails because it comes up with a load of dribble like %$%$^%^, unreadable. Anyway, is there a difference in eg (-5^2) than (-5)^2?

Comment: yes. the first one will return -5 and the second one 5

Comment: I did not mean to say the the history of edits, simply the updated version of the answer!

Comment: Does it work out?

Comment: on the website you linked me to, you put 8 rather than -8...But now it says the answer ( for the one you done ) is pie/4 :O

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=angle+between+%28-8%2C15%29+and%28-23%2C7%29

Comment: Yes! It could not find the angle before without taking the inverse of cosine, but now, it turns out quite nicely: $45^o$

Comment: you might want to take a look at the dot product: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors_and_spaces/dot_cross_products/v/vector-dot-product-and-vector-length

Comment: Hope it helps! If you find my answer helpful, please mark it as an answer! :) Feel free to ask more questions!

Comment: Hey, how did it work out to be 45 degrees could you explain ?

Comment: It's a conversion from rad to degrees: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian

Answer (score 3):

The dot product of two vectors in $\Bbb R^2$ is expressible in two ways:

$$\mathbf{u\cdot v} = |\mathbf{u}|\cdot|\mathbf{v}| \cos\theta$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors, and 
$$\mathbf{u\cdot v} = u_xv_x + u_yv_y$$

Equating these we have $$|\mathbf{u}||\mathbf{v}| \cos\theta = u_xv_x + u_yv_y.$$

In your problem, $u_x, u_y, v_x, v_y$ are given, and from these you can calculate $|\mathbf{u}||\mathbf{v}| = \sqrt{u_x^2 + u_y^2}\cdot\sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2}$.

Does that help?

Comment: Hey, if you bare with me i'll attempt what my interpretation of what you put in the first part, ill edit the post once ive done it and leave a comment here informing you. I'll try go step by step, thanks btw.

Comment: Ok i think i'm completely off lol... i tried doing the u.v

Comment: I got ( 184 -56 )                                                                                    -      -345  105